# Can not connect to DB2 using ibm_db api in Robot framework

Tags: python, db2, robotframework, db2-400

I used below statement to connect to DB2 database (on IBM i Access server) in RIDE editor

```
Connect To Database Using Custom Params    ibm_db    'DATABASE=mydb;HOSTNAME=10.53.x.x;PORT=8471;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=myuser;PWD=xxxx;','',''
```

But it always connecting and can not finishing. I can telnet the port 8471 (this is port for accessing database)

When I tried another port I got the below error:

```
SQL30081N A communication error has been
detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP". Communication
API being used: "SOCKETS". Location where the error was detected:
"x.x.x.x". Communication function detecting the error: "recv".
Protocol specific error code(s): "*", "*", "0". SQLSTATE=08001
```

Do you know how to fix this ?

Comment: what do you mean "always connecting and can not finishing" ?  give details. What messages appear in the Db2 client diagnostics ?

Comment: My mean RIDE editor show it still connecting .... for along time (not success)

Comment: Answer all questions. Any diagnostics from Db2 client?  Can you connect to the same database *on the command line* with the same credentials/port etc. Give details about your client, where python is running, your python version/bitness, and the ibm_db version.

Comment: I use ibm_db 2.0.8, I connect to DB2 server from RIDE editor, don't know about DB2 client. My python is intalled on remote machine (windows 8)

Comment: Has this ever worked? DB2 client connectivity to IBM i requires a chargeable licence. You may be better using the IBM i Access (or IBM i Access Client Solutions) ODBC or JDBC driver.

Comment: Yes, when I tried to use jaydebe instead of ibm_db, I got the problem about licence: SqlSyntaxErrorExceptionPyRaisable: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][t4][10509][13454][4.21.29] Connection to the data server failed. The IBM Data Server for JDBC and SQLJ license was invalid 
or was not activated for the DB2 for z/OS subsystem.

Comment: What is the actual driver you are using underneath ibm_db? Does it work correctly for other applications? If it is the standard IBM i JDBC driver, the one I mentioned previously, that would normally require jt400.jar in the classpath. I am also a bit nervous about the mention of z/OS - do you perhaps need to tell your application explicitly that we are talking IBM i not mainframe? The DB2 client stuff works the same with both, but the drivers I am talking about don't.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **ibm_db_dbi** instead of using **ibm_db**.

It worked for me .

Comment: That would make sense to me - see my comment above about IBM i specificity.

Comment: Hi, Using ibm_db_dbi, I got the same result